# Sometimes capitalized column name will be converted to lower case in MySQL windows?

Tags: mysql, capitalize

Like `accountId` -> `accountid`

Has anyone met this kind of problem?

It doesn't happen every day,though.

Comment: how do u insert it? and what language?

Comment: Not insert,it's defined when `create table...`

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html on quirks of MySQL case-sensivity..

Answer (score 3):

The capitalization is a configuration option, which is enabled by default on windows (and disabled on linux). From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

> Consequently, the case sensitivity of
>   the underlying operating system plays
>   a part in the case sensitivity of
>   database and table names. This means
>   database and table names are not case
>   sensitive in Windows, and case
>   sensitive in most varieties of Unix.

Comment: Which suxx, because you may store you record in an associative array which is case sensitive.

Comment: @Notinlist,that's how I discovered this problem!

Answer (score 3):

what do have when you run `SHOW VARIABLES`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-variables.html?

e.g. lower_case_table_names?

Comment: I forgot to check that,just `alter table change accountid accountId ...`.There should be a reason why it happens every several days

Comment: Does it affect the result of `mysqldump .. db`?I remembered that I used the output to re-create the database several days ago.